# SQL Use Text and Decimal in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to fill in all NULL fields with DEL. I don't want to modify the database tables, I would just like to do it in on column. Below is what I'm trying to do right now. Basically if the value is not null then I want 132.00. If it is null then I want to see DEL. I'm working on SQL 2008 R2. Thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

Current thought

```
CASE WHEN [Sales] IS NOT NULL 
     THEN CAST([Sales] AS decimal(10,0)) 
     ELSE 'DEL' 
 END AS Sales
```

Error

Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Comment: What is the type of Sales column? And DEL is a column or a string value?

Comment: Sales is Int and DEL is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN [Sales] IS NOT NULL 
     THEN CAST(CAST([Sales] AS decimal(10,0)) AS NVARCHAR(1000))
     ELSE CAST(DEL  AS NVARCHAR(1000))
 END AS Sales
```

In a case statement in every ease the returned data type must be the same.

**EDIT**

To return string `DEL` if sales is null you can do

```
CASE WHEN [Sales] IS NOT NULL 
     THEN CAST(CAST([Sales] AS decimal(10,0)) AS NVARCHAR(1000))
     ELSE 'DEL' 
 END AS Sales
```

Comment: DEL is not a column as I ask on the comments it is a string.

Comment: are you returning the string `'DEL'` if sales is null ??

Comment: Yes I'm trying to return 'DEL' if its null. Sorry I missed that in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't **store** the 'DEL' text in a column defined to hold decimals. It's just not possible. What is more, you *shouldn't* store decimal values in a columned defined to hold strings. In other words, this requirement is backwards and wrong.

What you can do is continue to store NULL and decimal data as you have before, and just return string data for display:

```
CASE WHEN [sales] IS NULL THEN 'DEL' ELSE Convert(varchar(13), [sales]) END
```

However, this is also less than the ideal, as it forces your database to do the conversion work, and means your client code starts out working with strings rather than numbers. The best option here is to have the database continue to work with the raw data as it is, and make the adjustment to change NULLs to 'DEL' in your *client code*.